# Google Analytics: Cross domain tracking with form post method doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

we have an e-shop with 3rd party shopping cart integrated.
We'd like to keep original referral for conversion that happens on 3rd party cart domain.

GA code in e-shop:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-33333-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga('linker:autoLink', ['3rdPartyCart.com'],false, true );
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

GA code in 3rd party:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-33333-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga('linker:autoLink', ['e-shop.com'], false, true );
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Both cart and e-shop added to Referral Exclusion List in GA.

When visitor ads item to a cart and wants to buy it he / she must click "checkout" button, which is a form with submit method and it leads to 3rd party cart with SSL.
We followed those guidelines: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autoforms , but it didn't work.
Simple link in text leading to cart works just fine and generates ?_ga=1.99283479872.98324798274 querystring, but form does not.

Any help would be appreciated, we really need to have this working...

Comment: might be better posting here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same problem, but I might have a solution for you, depending on your control over the cart.  If you have some degree of control over the server-side of your 3rd party cart, you could pass the Google Analytics client id as a querystring parameter in the action of your order form.

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.third-party-cart.com?clientId=000000">
```

Then, on the cart page, you could retrieve it as a GET parameter, by doing something like

```
$clientId = $_GET['clientId'];
```

in php or the equivalent in whatever server-side language the shopping cart uses.  Alternatively, you could pass it as a form input:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.third-party-cart.com?">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientId" value="000000">
</form>
```

And then you'd retrieve it on the cart page somehow if possible.  Depending on your cart solution, there might be some custom variables that they allow to be passed, so you might want to look into what those would be.